# Windows 7 randomly freezes on some HP 400 Pro One

Tags: windows-7, freeze, all-in-one

We have about 100 HP 400 Pro One installed and a very few (like six or eight of them) experience system freezes so hard we have to reboot them, and we are at a lose of what's causing it.

The computers have Windows 7 Pro installed from factory, the only thing we configure is to remove some of the "added value" from HP they bring with them and install our custom software. Since we detected the freezes, we have tried to stop uninstalling the crapware, updating the drivers both from the last from HP and the manufactures of the individual pieces, and updating the BIOS, without success.

It can take weeks for a machine to freeze, so we can't use Process Monitor to check the problem. Would it work? I haven't used it for storing more than a couple reboots worth of data.

TL;DR

- About 5% of our HP 400 AIO Pro One freeze on normal usage, it can take hours or weeks, with no information at the event viewer nor blue screen. Just frozen. They don't recover. It doesn't matter the usage.
- We don't have a clear suspect. As new HP are so terrible with the USB connections, we think it could be something connected to them. It could be also a software problem, but all the computers have the same software installed, so it would be a software+hardware/network problem.
- The freezes don't leave any log that we are aware of. Just a "This machine was improperly shutdown" at the event viewer once we reboot them.
- They come right from HP, so is not malware nor a "sfc" like problem. Still we did check, just in case. They also pass all the system checks from HP, memtest, victoria, seagate tools, burning tests for days long.
- We thought we had found it when we detected some of them with the network lights stuck, and upon reboot, Windows didn't detect the ethernet connection. We have to power cycle them to get it back. We  unchecked all the energy savings from the network card settings, but they still freeze.

Any ideas or point to any software we can use to track the origin of the problem?

Edit 20141207: Maybe the network cards?

Edit 20141211: Is not the network cards, at least, from the energy savings. We are so desperated we have tried to contact HP, and they have no idea, as expected.

Comment: "About 5% of our HP 400 AIO Pro One freeze on normal usage" - have you spoken to HP?

Comment: "Hello HP? I have this problem that is not happening now nor can't reproduce it" We have a much worse problem, trivial to reproduce, with our hundreds of installed HP 600 and 800, and support from HP and our retailer has been abismal.